# Vector equation of a line defined by two planes

Tags: vectors, parametric, plane-geometry

*"Given two planes:*

$ 3x+4y-z=2 $
$ -2x+y+2z=6 $

*Find and equation of the line defined by the intersection of these planes.*

I have found the normal vectors, and cross-producted them. But I am not sure what to do next.

Thanks

Comment: The cross product is a direction vector for the line of intersection. All you need is a point on that line. There are infinitely many points on the line. You only need one. Choose a value for one of the variables, $x$ say, plug it into both equations, then solve the resulting system of $2$ equations for $y$ and $z$. That gives you a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the line. Using that point and the direction vector, you presumably know how to get the vector equation for the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$ 3x+4y-z=2 $
$ -2x+y+2z=6 $

So let's set $x=0\implies 4y-z=2, y+2z=6$ so $9y=10\implies y=\frac{10}9, z=\frac{22}9$
So because a line $r$ is equal to $\vec a+t\vec b$

You have $r=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{10}9\\\frac{22}9\end{bmatrix}+t\vec b$ while $\vec b$ is the result of the cross product